# IE 9 Form Submit Crash

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication

I'm using an encryption technique on a user login form to avoid passing passwords in plain text.  I store a unique challenge value in a PHP session, include that same value within an HTML form hidden field, and then I use a JavaScript-based SHA1-1 script to hash the password before submitting it.  (It's then compared with the same at the server side using the challenge stored in the session variable).

I don't have any problems with the above in itself, but I thought it best to explain why I need to do this.

I'm submitting the form like this:

```
var password = sha1(document.forms['loginform'].password.value);
password = sha1(document.forms['loginform'].challenge.value + password);
document.forms['loginform'].challenge.value = '';
document.forms['loginform'].password.value = password;
document.forms['loginform'].style.display = 'none';
document.forms['loginform'].submit();
```

The problem is the 5th line there.  I'd like to hide the encrypted password value from view, because if I don't, I have people saying 'that wasn't my password', 'I don't like that', and so on.

The thing is, setting display to 'none' prior to submit, seems to crash Internet Explorer 9 with a message like this:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   iexplore.exe
Application Version:    9.0.8112.16421
Fault Module Name:  MSHTML.dll
```

So, I was wondering if anyone has a better way to go about doing this.  I.e., is there a good or 'normal' way to hide a JavaScript updated form value before submit?

Thanks

Edit:
For now I'm setting the password field text colour to match the background.  It's a bit of a hack.  I don't want to mark the below as the answer - I don't really agree and it's a bit like a thumbs down for my own question.  (I will, rather than leave this open forever : ).  It's no major problem.  I'll leave it for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Such "encryption technique" does nothing helpful. You are still passing the passwords in plain text. Imaging someone use a sniffer and have got the password hash (and the session cookie..), He can login the system easily.

If you want security, use **https**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  No, I'm not passing passwords in plain text, I'm passing them combined with a unique code and hashed, and that has to be a step up from passing, you know, 'apple' in the HTTP headers.  Data protection is my concern as much as preventing security breaches on this particular site.

Comment: @stackuser10210 I mean if you don't use https, nothing can be security. Your http request can be stole what it is.

Comment: It's an extra measure taken and quite worthwhile in the era of internet cafes etc.  This isn't my invenetion.  Yahoo have been using something similar for email logins for a while (predating HTTPS for every login, I think).  I think they probably use an async post (not sure).  I didn't want to resort to that.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered a similar issue ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080706/debugging-an-ie-crash)). Microsoft's IE development team has confirmed that it is a rendering issue. If this is the same thing, it seems to not be related to the form submission, but rather it occurs when setting the value of an input field and immediately hiding the field's parent when certain styles are assigned ([see above link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080706/debugging-an-ie-crash)). Microsoft's suggestion was to force IE to use the IE8 rendering engine, but I discovered that wrapping the input in another element (e.g. SPAN or DIV) with no styles seems to do the trick.

Let me know if this workaround works for you.